# Who tore down the walls of Jerusalem in Nehemiah?

Tags: history, historical-interpretation, nehemiah, jerusalem

This is the verse in question:

> "And they said to me, “The survivors who are left from the captivity in the province are there in great distress and reproach. The wall of Jerusalem is also broken down, and its gates are burned with fire.”- **Nehemiah 1:3**

Answer (score 2):

here is the answer

"The entire Babylonian army that was with the captain of the guard tore down the walls around Jerusalem."  2 Kings 25:10